# Type 1 conditional for past or Type 2 condition

Tags: conditional-constructions

Please help me understand the type of sentence below. Is it **"Type 1 conditionals for past"** or **"Type 2"**?

> *"If we didn't have lectures the next day, we would usually stay up late talking or watching TV*"

I read this sentence in Oxford verb and tense book under " Type 0 and  Type 1 conditionals for past".

To me it looks like type 2 condition as it matches type 2 condition structure: ***If + past tense + would***.

Comment: Are you not convinced by my answer or do you have an inquiry im mind?

Comment: Ok, Good. Best of luck. I could see that you didn't verify my answer so I thought maybe you didn't like it, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said,  the tenses match the 2nd type so this is a 2nd type conditional sentence although I think it would be more natural if type 0 was used here, something like: 
" - If we don't have lectures the next day, we usually stay up late."

So it would be better to use type 0 conditional as it states a normal habit. If the sentence is put under "type 0 and type 1" section,  then I think it must be a typo as I said that it'd be better to use type 0 conditional and that is what should have been used in this section.